# Get the number of created Wikipedia articles during a specific period of time

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to get number of articles written/created in some language (say English) during a specific week (say last week). How can I run this query on Wikipedia?

I have no experience in **wikipedia-api**

Comment: Have you *searched* the API docs?

Comment: unfortunately i have no experience there. I appreciate if you direct me

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this query on the Wikipedia database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM enwiki_p.recentchanges
WHERE rc_new = 1
AND rc_namespace = 0
AND rc_timestamp BETWEEN 20160417000000 AND 20160424000000
```

See the results [here](https://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/9324). If you want to count the number of new articles for another language, you can change `enwiki_p` to another [two-character language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias#Detailed_list).